# Regarding encrypting web.config using nant

Tags: c#, nant

I have a question that can we run via command line:

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "DRMBasic" -exp
```

using NAnt build script.

I was trying the following line of code.

```
<exec failonerror="true" verbose="true" commandline="aspnet_regiis -pc 'DRMBasic' -exp" />
```

but somehow this command can't run because the path is 
`c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727` to run the above aspnet_regiis. I can also get the framework path. but what to do with it is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path, just set the workingdir and basedir attributes on  task like so:

```
<exec 
     program="aspnet_regiis" 
     basedir="c:\path to aspnet_regiis" 
     workingdir="c:\working dir"
     ...
>
   <arg value="-pc"/>
   <arg value="DRMBasic/>
   ...
</exec>
```